# MySQL - Jump to "foo:Begin" in Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

For example, I've code like this:

```
...
PROCEDURE procedure1(... some parameters ...)
BEGIN
  DECLARE l_xxx VARCHAR(5);

  SET l_xxx = 'ERROR';

  IF l_xxx = 'ERROR' THEN
     -- in this section, I want to call 'foo' process below
  END IF;

  foo:BEGIN
     -- Some process
  END;
END;
```

Can I call the `error:BEGIN` in a stored procedure..?

Answer (score 1):

1. You could create another stored procedure, and call it instead of GOTO-like command.
2. Try to do it using IF-THEN statement with a help of user variable.

For example:

```
DECLARE l_xxx VARCHAR(5);

SET l_xxx = 'ERROR';
SET @a = NULL;

IF l_xxx = 'ERROR' THEN
  SET @a = 1; -- Set error flag
END IF;

IF @a IS NULL THEN
  -- Some process, when there were no errors.
END IF;

IF @a = 1 THEN
  BEGIN
  -- Some process
  END;
END IF;
```